# total cache plugin write permission to my wp-content folder?

Tags: wordpress

This is the first time i am working with wordpress and i am a bit confused about this requirement.A weird requirement by the plugin indeed
Its asking me to :

> Files and directories could not be automatically created to
>   complete the installation. Please enter FTP details below to complete
>   the setup. Also try chmod 777 /var/www/my-project/wp-content

Well i am not sure that its safe to give permission 777 to my wp-content folder.
It is really required?

Comment: "Also make sure wp-content/ and wp-content/uploads/ (temporarily) have 777 permissions before proceeding" - http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/w3-total-cache/installation/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dont worry !!!! It is not asking permanently.You have to give this permission for the installation time only as it have to write things in your wp-content.After installation it will tell you to make it back to the default 755.Probably the massege will appear like this in your case.

```
/var/www/my-project/wp-content is write-able. When finished installing the plugin, change the permissions back to the default: chmod 755 /var/www/my-project/wp-content. Permissions are currently 777
```

So start installing. and be happy :-)

Answer (score 2):

I idea is that you set 777 permission on the wp-content dir while you do the install and then revert the permissions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.+1 for the answer  accepted the other one because of 1 minute earlier.