# After installed W3 Total cache, Some error are showing

Tags: wordpress, w3-total-cache

I have installed the W3 Total cache but It is showing error and errors are "(1) FTP credentials don't allow to copy to file /u2/www/00authors/wp-content/advanced-cache.php" "(2) W3 Total Cache Error: Files and directories could not be automatically created to complete the installation."

So How do i solve these?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16219703/total-cache-plugin-write-permission-to-my-wp-content-folder

Comment: are you using WpEngine hosting?

Comment: @charankumar no i am not using WpEngine hosting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to FTP in to your server and manually create the advanced-cache.php document. The content for the file can be found here:

https://github.com/crowdfavorite-mirrors/wp-w3-total-cache/blob/master/wp-content/advanced-cache.php

Comment: I have did same as you said, Now the error "FTP credentials don't allow to copy to file /u2/www/00authors/wp-content/advanced-cache.php"